# Enumeration of arbitrary length

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I am trying to get TeX to produce the following list:

1. Test1
2. Test2
3. Test3

   .

   .

   .

n. Testn

To be clear, the list you see above is literally what I am trying to produce. I am not asking how to produce this list for a given value of n. I want to produce the first three terms, then put \vdots in the appropriate place, and end with \item[n.] Testn. Thanks for the help!

Comment: It would be helpful to show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Answer (score 5):

Surely doing this manually is fine?  Or am I missing something?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[]
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\item Item 3
\item[]{$\vdots$} 
%\item[]{.}
%\item[]{.}
%\item[]{.}
\item[$n$.]{}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Using `\vdots`

[image: output of code]

Alternative version (commented lines)

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 5):

I like better this layout:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem, mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Test 1.
\item Test 2.
\item Test 3.\vspace*{-2\itemsep}
\item[$\vdotswithin{n.}$]\leavevmode\vspace*{-2\itemsep}
\item[$n$.] Test $ n $. 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item[1.] Test 1
  \item[2.] Test 2
  \item[3.] Test 3
  \newline $\vdots$
  \item[n.] Test n
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

to produce

[image]

Comment: Thank you Andrew. My only issue with your way is that it seems that vdots are a somehow a part of item 3. Is that considered good style?

Comment: @TexHelpPlease Possibly not. Use one of Alan's suggestions  instead.

Answer (score 1):

Write this in the form of a macro `\listto{<n>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\listto}[1]{%
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item Item 3
    \item[] $\vdots$
    \item[#1.] Item #1
  \end{enumerate}
}

\begin{document}

\listto{$n$}

\end{document}
```